# How can I save groups of open tabs in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

How can I save a set of open tabs in IntelliJ, so that I can switch between Git branches and bring up sets of working files for each?

Thank you.

Comment: By "open tabs", do you mean code editor windows?

Comment: And if you want to save terminal tabs as well vote for this one: [IDEA-117946](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-117946)

Answer (score 152, accepted):

You can save a context, which includes a set of open tabs along with some other information such as the active run configurations. Use `Tools | Tasks & Contexts | Save Context...` to save a context, and the corresponding `Load Context...` action to switch to a saved context.

**Note:** Make sure that you have ["Task Management" plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11545-task-management) enabled if you don't see these options in the menu.

Comment: Yes!! This is one of the most useful features in IDEA. You can even configure some servers (For instance `JIRA`) and work on a specific issue or story. Then when switching between tasks everything will be switched for you: open tabs, git branch, code pointer (cursor), and change list which is a very useful feature as well (you can find it under `changes` tab)

Comment: I also found that you can do this more quickly with the dropdown in the upper right. And another note, it saves breakpoints. Thanks!

Comment: Ooh, which dropdown? I can't find it.

Comment: @BlondCode You may not have the Task Management plugin enabled. (I didn't!) It is built in and enabled by default, but may not be in your case. See [intellij help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/managing-tasks-and-context.html)

Comment: It seems like there is no way to save/update the current context. You have to keep creating a new one and deleting the old one. ?

Comment: IntelliJ's "contexts" are pretty clumsy (I've also used Jetbrain's Rubymine, AppCode, and IntelliJ). I especially realized this once I became proficient with Xcode. You shouldn't have to save/load contexts. They should just exist and automatically save. The context should be numbered. This is how Xcode does it. :(

Comment: I have IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate and the Tasks & Contexts menu was not enabled. Perhaps I disabled it during installation. I had to go to the Install Plugins dialog and enable this feature for the menu item to appear.

Comment: @yole: is it possible to export the context similar to how one can export the Intellij settings?. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58733835/is-it-possible-to-export-the-context-of-intellij-tools-taskscontexts

Comment: Tasks Management plug-in does not appear to be enabled by default in GoLand (JetBrains for Go), but it is available in the Plugin Marketplace.