# Is it possible to export the context of Intellij (Tools->Tasks&Contexts)

Tags: intellij-idea

I usually use contexts(https://stackoverflow.com/a/28804934/6700081) in Intellij to save multiple opened tabs so that I can easily switch between group of tabs when I need.

Is there a way to export these context settings?

---

I see that Intellij IDE saves the context details in MAC in the location like `/Users/firstpostcommenter/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea2019.1/tasks/project_folder_name.contexts.zip` (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs)

I tried to use the context zip folder in another copy of the same project by manually updating the context file(duplicating the `project_folder_name.contexts.zip` to `project_folder_name_COPY.contexts.zip` and manually updating context file content to refer to the new path/location) but it does not reflect in the IDE. I couldn't find how the name of the context is saved and referred by the IDE

Please note that if I just copy paste the context zip folder without editing it then it reflects in the IDE. I am not sure what I am doing wrong when editing the file to point to different workspace location?

Comment: It is not possible. Here is related request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-77555

Comment: @Andrey: Yes, looks like it is probably not possible out-of-the-box from Intellij. But Atleast my way of updating the file manually should have worked, I will see if someone cares to comment what I did wrong. If I use the same context.zip folder (with a different name) without editing it then it works fine. So, this kind of manual copy/paste seems to work but if I edit the context file to update the folder paths then it stops working in IDE

Comment: We cannot export context out-of-the-box from Intellij IDEA IDE.

But if you need it for backup purpose or when changing your computer then I *guess* the below method will work although I did not try it:-,
Copy the context.zip file and save it as backup. 
Move to new computer and create the workspace/checkout project in the same location as mentioned in the context files present in the context.zip folder (so this is not possible when moving from MAC to PC and vice versa).
Paste the context.zip file in the new machine in the tasks folder